# No busca los valores internos del array

Tags: javascript

Cuando introduzco el nombre del jugador, no me devuelve la posicion en la que esta en el array.

```
function elementos(){
    let jugador = new Array("Watt","Fitzpatrick","Dupree","Smith-schuster","Hayward");
    let posicion;
    let contador=0;

posicion = parseInt(prompt("Escribe el nombre de un jugador"));

for (let posicion of jugador)
    {
     if (posicion<6){
        console.log(posicion);
     }
    }

    alert("El jugador esta en la posicion: " + posicion);

}
```

Comment: parseInt de un nombre?

Answer (score 2):

Estas haciendo mal la forma de lectura, no puedes pasar un nombre a entero, arregle un poco tu código, recuerda que el arreglo comienza de 0 también.

Uso un `foreach` para iterar, luego de esto igualo lo leído en el `prompt` y el element de mi recorrido, uso tu `contador` (que no utilizas), para mostrar la posición.

```js
function elementos(){ 
let jugador = new Array("Watt","Fitzpatrick","Dupree","Smith-schuster","Hayward"); 
let posicion; 
let contador=0;

posicion = prompt("Escribe el nombre de un jugador");

jugador.forEach(element => {
  if(posicion == element){
    alert("El jugador esta en la posicion: " + contador);
  }
  contador++;
});

}
elementos()
```